# A mouseover button in a post starts blinking?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two div-elements where one representing a post (status post) and one representing a delete-button for deletion of the post. The delete-button shall only be shown on `mouseover` event of div-element representing the post. It shall also be shown on `mouseover` event of the delete-button itself, because it lies within the post.

```
document.getElementById('statusPost').addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
   var deleteButton = document.createElement('div');
   deleteButton.id = 'deleteButton';
   deleteButton.className = 'deleteButton';
   this.appendChild(deleteButton);
},false);

document.getElementById('statusPost').addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
   this.removeChild(deleteButton);
},false);
```

Now the problem is that on `mouseover` in the delete-button, the delete button starts blinking? The delete-button lies within the post, like Facebook. It is like on `mouseover` on the delete-button is treated as `mouseout` of the div-element representing the post. So that's why it starts blinking. That's at least what I think. How do I solve this so in the event of `mouseover` on the delete-button, which lies within the post, it stops blinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to actually remove the delete button from the DOM or is it ok to just hide it?  If you can, it's always best to use a CSS only approach:

```
.deleteButton
{
    display: none;
}
.statusPost:hover .deleteButton
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much this little annoying problem was very time consuming. Really appreciate you taking your time to solve my problem.